On which site can I ask about a language model smoothing algorithm?
I have a question regarding a language model smoothing algorithm and I posted it on Stack Overflow where I got a comment saying that it isn't quite right for the site and that I should try elsewhere. I checked the sites that are part of Stack Exchange but I couldn't determine which site fits best.
My original question was a combination of code and CompSci formulas and the translation of the formulas into C++. As it wasn't directly connected to how C++ operates I see how it wasn't the best fit but as I don't want to go around every StackExchange site asking if the question is right for the forum, I am asking this here in hopes someone can lead me in the right direction. Thank you for any and all help.
As per the request here is the whole question I was going to ask:

How do I correct the perplexity of my Bigram language model with good turing smoothing increasing with the size of training sets?
As an assignment in my masters course we were given an assignment to create bigram and trigram language models and use different forms of smoothing to see how each method affects the perplexity of the model. Our smoothing methods consist of Good-Turing smoothing and Kneser-ney smoothing, but I am stuck at the Good-Turing smoothing method.
My current issue is when I train the model on a training set and then calculate the perplexity on the same set I get a certain value but if I increase the size of the training set and train again the perplexity I calculate is higher than with a smaller set. I understand that perplexity directly translates to the capability of a model and a larger training set should be able to predict continuations more accurately which would result in a smaller perplexity, which isn't what I am facing.
I've tried looking around for more details on Good-Turing smoothing but I was unable to come up with a formula that would correct my problem.
As an assignment in my masters course we were given an assignment to create bigram and trigram language models and use different forms of smoothing to see how each method affects the perplexity of the model. Our smoothing methods consist of Good-Turing smoothing and Kneser-ney smoothing, but I am stuck at the Good-Turing smoothing method.
My current issue is when I train the model on a training set and then calculate the perplexity on the same set I get a certain value but if I increase the size of the training set and train again the perplexity I calculate is higher than with a smaller set. I understand that perplexity directly translates to the capability of a model and a larger training set should be able to predict continuations more accurately which would result in a smaller perplexity, which isn't what I am facing.
I've tried looking around for more details on Good-Turing smoothing but I was unable to come up with a formula that would correct my problem.
For the smoothing I used my professors formula which looks like this: 
where I am calculating (1 * N1)/N0 (N1 and N0 being the number of bigrams that appear once and 0 times respectively). And for the calculation of probability of unseen bigrams (that don't appear in the training set) I used this formula:

As for N0 I used the approximation formula:

Where V is the size of the vocabulary and Nb is the number of unique bigrams in the model.
As for the perplexity calculations I used this formula:

m in this case is the number of unique bigrams in the set.
Noting all of this here is my current code. I have a bigram model defined as:
typedef unordered_map<string, int> UnigramCounts;
typedef unordered_map<string, UnigramCounts> BigramCounts;

class BigramModel {
private:
    UnigramCounts unigrams;
    BigramCounts bigrams;
    double modelUnseenBigramProbability;
public:
    void train(const vector<string>& sentences);
    void smoothGoodTuring();
    void serialize(const string& filename);
    void deserialize(const string& filename);
    double calculatePerplexity(const vector<string>& words);
};

My training function is a simple nested for loop to go over preprocessed words of my training set and build unigrams and bigrams like so:
void BigramModel::train(const vector<string>& words) {
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        unigrams[words[i]]++;
        
        if (i < words.size() - 1) {
            bigrams[words[i]][words[i + 1]]++;
        }
    }
}

Then I use the smoothing function to go over the model and smooth out the bigram counts and calculate the unseen bigram probability (which Good-Turing is supposedly good at) and store that into the model class like so:
void BigramModel::smoothGoodTuring() {
    unordered_map<int, int> countOfCounts;
    int totalBigrams = 0;
    int uniqueBigrams = 0;
    int unseenBigrams = 0;

    for (const auto& prevWord : bigrams) {
        for (const auto& entry : prevWord.second) {
            countOfCounts[entry.second]++;
            totalBigrams += entry.second;
            uniqueBigrams++;
            if (entry.second == 1) {
                unseenBigrams++;
            }
        }
    }

    int vocabulary = unigrams.size();
    double zeroProbBigramEstimate = vocabulary * vocabulary - uniqueBigrams;
    double unseenBigramProb = ((double)unseenBigrams / zeroProbBigramEstimate) / totalBigrams;
    modelUnseenBigramProbability = unseenBigramProb;

    // Apply Good-Turing smoothing to bigram probabilities
    for (auto& prevWord : bigrams) {
        for (auto& entry : prevWord.second) {
            int count = entry.second;
            if (countOfCounts.find(count + 1) != countOfCounts.end() && countOfCounts.find(count) != countOfCounts.end()) {
                double smoothedCount = ((count + 1) * ((double)countOfCounts[count + 1] / countOfCounts[count])) / totalBigrams;
                entry.second = round(smoothedCount * totalBigrams);
            }
            else {
                entry.second = round(unseenBigramProb * totalBigrams);
            }
        }
    }
}

And finally I calculate the perplexity like so:
double BigramModel::calculatePerplexity(const vector<string>& words) {
    
    double logProb = 0;
    int uniqueBigrams = 0;
    double prob = 0;
    set<pair<string, string>> uniqueBigramsSet;

    for (int i = 1; i < words.size(); ++i) {
        if (uniqueBigramsSet.find({ words[i - 1], words[i] }) == uniqueBigramsSet.end()) {
            // Increment unique bigrams count and add to the set
            uniqueBigrams++;
            uniqueBigramsSet.insert({ words[i - 1], words[i] });
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < uniqueBigrams; ++i) {
        double probability;
        if (uniqueBigramsSet.find({ words[i - 1], words[i] }) != uniqueBigramsSet.end() && bigrams[words[i - 1]][words[i]] != 0) {
            probability = (double)bigrams[words[i - 1]][words[i]] / unigrams[words[i - 1]];
        }
        else {
            probability = modelUnseenBigramProbability;
        }        

        logProb += log2(probability);

    }

    cout << logProb << endl;
    double perplexity = logProb / -uniqueBigrams;
    return perplexity;
}

I've tried changing the formulas many times but this is as close as I get to the "correct" answer but I still get higher perplexities when I have larger training sets. What is my mistake?
